# DFP %%PATTERN%% not rendering in creative

Tags: google-dfp

I'm using DFP to target an ad slot using custom criteria for example:

```
googletag.defineSlot("/example/adunit", [728, 90], "div-gpt-ad-123456789-0")
.addService(googletag.pubads())
.setTargeting("var1", "value");
```

And in my creative I am writing the equivalent macro in the creative to output the value:

```
%%PATTERN:var1%%
```

The problem is, I know that the custom attribute is being provided to DFP because it is targeting the correct ad and you can see custom criteria in the request (viewing through Fiddler) but the macro does not render the value in the creative.

I've followed the advice in the documentation but I can't see where things are failing. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Are there any restrictions on how and where you can use this macro?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the full contents of the creative?

Comment: There are some restrictions on macro's values For example, > The values of key-values cannot contain any of the following special characters: " ' , = ! + # * ~ ; ^ ( ) < > [ ] See [Rules and limitations around key-values in GPT ad tags](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1697712#use_key-value_targeting_with_GPT)